# Uniform formatting of a selection of cells in various tables with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, formatting, jquery-selectors

I have a page which contains several tables, and I would like to format each table so that the second cell of each other row has a specific background color.
I have tried the following jQuery code as suggested in an answer to the initial version of this question :

```
   $('table tr:odd td:nth-child(2)').css("background-color", "#F6F3EE");
```

This works fine as long as all tables have an even number of rows. If that is not the case, the formatting is inverted, as if jQuery considered the s as being part of one single table and doesn't reinitiate the counter at each table.

Here's a link to a js fiddle to illustrate the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eAHUF/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're selecting only the first `td` element that is the descendent of a `tr.reg:even` row.

Try using the `:nth-child()` alternative:

```
$('table tr:odd td:nth-child(2)').css('background-color','#ffa');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eAHUF/).

**Note**: you have to remember that the CSS `:nth-child()` is one-based, not zero-based (as JavaScript is).

---

**Edited** in response to OP's comment, below:

> ...but it presents me with a problem. I've edited your jsfiddle demo to add a row in the first table thus giving it an uneven number of rows. Now the second table's rows are reversely highlighted which is not what I was looking for. Do you have a fix for this ?

Yeah, I...missed the obvious (somehow). I've amended the above code to look at each `table` in turn and then look for the `:odd` rows and the `nth-child()`:

```
$('table').find('tr:odd td:nth-child(2)').css('background-color','#ffa');​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eAHUF/2/).

References:

- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`:nth-child()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).
- [`:odd` selector](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/).

Comment: @David-thomas Your answer looked correct at first, but it presents me with a problem. I've edited your jsfiddle demo to add a row in the first table thus giving it an uneven number of rows. Now the second table's rows are reversely highlighted which is not what I was looking for. Do you have a fix for this ?

Comment: I've edited, and corrected, the answer. My apologies, I'm not sure why I hadn't noticed the former flaws... =/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('table tr.reg:even td:eq(1)').each(function(index) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#F4F4F8");
});
```

Comment: Why use `each()`? It's unnecessary, since `css()` will act on all the elements returned by the array, `each()` is only necessary when you need to iterate over the elements to perform different actions on them based on their index, or content...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is just:

```
$("table tr:even td:nth-child(2)").css("background-color", "#F4F4F8");
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/rowanmanning/pBCkj/